# What is the most maintainable approach to generating Javascript/ExtJS code from PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, code-generation

I'm creating a PHP framework which allows a PHP developer to create an ExtJS front end with PHP classes only, e.g. creating a grid looks like this:

```
$grid_import = new Backend_Layout_Grid('smart_worksheets');
$grid_import->set_width(1300);
$grid_import->set_rows_selectable(true);
$grid_import->set_title(__('backend.application.import.grid.title'));
$grid_import->set_margin('10px'); //CSS syntax, e.g. also "10px 0 0 0"
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'name', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.worksheetstoimport'), 'width'=>'300'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'kind', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.kind'), 'width'=>'50'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'file_size', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.sizebyte'), 'datatype' => 'int'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'when_file_copied', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.whenfilecopied'), 'datatype' => 'datetime', 'width'=>'150'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'table_name', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.mysqltablename'), 'width'=>'300'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'when_table_created', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.whentablecreated'), 'width'=>'160'));
$grid_import->add_column(array('id_code'=>'status', 'label'=> __('backend.application.import.status'), 'width'=>'300'));

$grid_import->set_doubleclick_target_uri('backend/application/importmanager/single', 0);

if (count($smart_worksheets) > 0)
{
    $row_index = 0;
    foreach ($smart_worksheets as $smart_worksheet)
    {
        $show_row = array(
            'name' => $smart_worksheet['name'],
            'kind' => $smart_worksheet['kind'],
            'file_size' => $smart_worksheet['file_size'],
            'when_file_copied' => $smart_worksheet['when_file_copied'],
            'table_name' => $smart_worksheet['table_name'],
            'when_table_created' => __($smart_worksheet['when_table_created']),
            'status' => __($smart_worksheet['status'])
        );
        $grid_import->add_row($show_row);
        if(in_array($smart_worksheet['status'], array('backend.application.import.status.needtoimport', 'backend.application.import.status.needtoreimport'))) {
            $grid_import->add_row_format($row_index, Backend_Layout_Grid::ROW_FORMAT_RED);
        }
        if(in_array($smart_worksheet['status'], array('backend.application.import.status.isuptodate'))) {
            $grid_import->add_row_format($row_index, Backend_Layout_Grid::ROW_FORMAT_GREEN);
        }

        if(intval($smart_worksheet['file_size']) > 4000000 AND (in_array($smart_worksheet['kind'], array('XLS','XLSX'))))
        {
            $grid_import->add_row_format($row_index, Backend_Layout_Grid::ROW_FORMAT_GRAY);
        }

        $row_index++;
    }
}

Backend_Layout_Window::instance()->add_item($grid_import);
```

It works well so far, but since I am just outputting javascript code line-by-line, the more features I build into the class, the more complex the if/then logic gets in building the raw Javascript text, here is a **typical method** which generates the Javascript code:

```````````
public function render_main_code_block()
{
    $retval = '';

    $retval .= $this->render_data_variable();
    $retval .= $this->render_array_reader_block();
    $retval .= $this->render_grid_panel_block();


    if($this->rows_selectable)
    {
        $retval .= self::render_line("````}),");
        $retval .= self::render_line("````sm: sm,");
    }

    $retval .= self::render_line("````viewConfig: {");


    if ($this->percentage_columns)
    {
        $retval .= self::render_line("``````forceFit: true,"); // true = percentage column width (add up to 100)
    }
    else
    {
        $retval .= self::render_line("``````forceFit: false,");
    }

    $retval .= self::render_line("``````getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){");
    if (count($this->row_formats) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($this->row_formats as $row_index => $row_format)
        {
            $retval .= self::render_line("````````if(rowIndex == ".$row_index."){");
            $retval .= self::render_line("``````````return '".$row_format."';");
            $retval .= self::render_line("````````}");
        }
    }
    $retval .= self::render_line("````````return '';");
    $retval .= self::render_line("``````}");
    $retval .= self::render_line("````},");

    $retval .= self::render_line("````title: '$this->title',");
    if ( ! is_null($this->width))
    {
        $retval .= self::render_line("````width: $this->width,");
    }
    $retval .= $this->render_double_click_handler();
    $retval .= self::render_line("````autoHeight: true,");
    $retval .= self::render_line("````frame: true");
    $retval .= self::render_line("``});");
    $retval .= self::render_line("");

    $retval .= self::render_line("``replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, ".$this->script_variable_name.");");
    $retval .= self::render_line("``".$this->script_variable_name.".getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();");


    // for word wrapping in columns
    $retval .= self::render_line("``function columnWrap(val){");
    $retval .= self::render_line("````return '<div style=\"white-space:normal !important;\">'+ val +'</div>';");
    $retval .= self::render_line("``}");

    return $retval;
}
```````````

Some particular issues which is starting to make this code too complex to maintain is:

- the simple fact that in lists of properties, only the **last item does not have a comma**. So far, I have been able to put have required properties at the end of the list so that the item without the comma is always included.

[image]

- and some features (such as adding checkboxes to a grid or not) **require code insertions in up to four different places in the javascript code**, and I can imagine there are features which will require the existing code to be restructured, so if the feature is turned on, the surrounding code needs to be e.g. contained within another section of the object

So at some point I want to **refactor** the way I create the Javascript.

I currently see only **one option really**, to create e.g. a `CodeFactory` class which contains e.g. `ExtJsVariable` to which I add objects which contain objects themselves recursively, the objects can be of type e.g. `simpleArray` or `anonymousFunction` etc, and then to create the code I would output `$codeFactory->render()` which would give me the code based on all of its internal objects:

[image]

**What are other options or code generation frameworks I could use to make the generation of this Javascript/ExtJS code from PHP more maintainable and straightforward?**

Comment: maybe http://www.ext4yii.com/ will give you more information.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to avoid JS generation dynamically as much as possible and keep all the Javascript in static JS files (factories, builders in your case most probably). And feed them with JSON data generated from the server. That seriously improve the structure and will make your application much easier to maintain. You may want to read about Factory and Builder patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I have been going through similar way of creating ExtJS code from PHP, or specifically, from CakePHP.

In my company, I am responsible on creating application framework which will speed up application production, so I actually come out with our first generation framework, which is similar to your idea: Generating codes through PHP.

Then quickly I realize that is pretty heavy for the server, and slow. Each request you get you need to regenerate the codes, which is impractical. Shortly after I come out with the second generation, with caching ability. Generated JS codes get cached into static files, and being included dynamically when needed. Reason for caching is because most of the time the JS codes are static, changes are the content, store etc.

So this method works for couple of months, until I finally realize this is not the correct way, for example,

- `TreePanel` cannot be generated through this way, especially with dynamic menu.
- ACL cannot interfering the cached code
- Can't have dynamic columns in the grid
- My framework is designed badly that I need to cache the codes before seeing the result - slow development.
- Hard to maintain, hard to call. Simple things like adding one config or remove one config can be tedious. Just like it's so tedious to use `FormHelper` to complete simple stuff.

So then I completely rewrite my code base, redesign everything, until I come up with this current beautiful ExtJS + CakePHP framework, which:

- Generic GridPanel/Store/View/Pagination/Editor components was created, and with just some simple configuration, you get a complete REST grid that hook up to one of Cake's controller. In Cake you include the one of the specially designed component, and just with few lines of code you created a full working REST grid.
- Specially designed Viewport which provides similar look and feel, with specially designed TreePanel (Menu), TabPanel (Contents)
- And many other generic, useful components being packed together, like Wizard, FieldEditor, UserImport... etc.
- And because they are all extendable ExtJS components, you can use it, extend it, fully customize it to whatever you want.

Sorry if this doesn't sound right to you, but personally I have gone through this, and I am really unhappy with the result of generating codes from PHP. You basically end up complicates the whole process, or slow thing down.

Sorry for my bad english by the way. And thanks for reading this.

And I cannot share my code nor open source it because it's part of company's property.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a few suggestions, as I have done some of this as well.

First of all move as much as you can into library classes
Second you can create a PHP data structure and turn it into a JSON with `json_encode`

And finally Keep it simple!